# Can someone explain why this code does not work the way i want?

Tags: python

Take three numbers from user, and print the biggest.

```
num1 = int(input(" Num1: "))
num2 = int(input(" Num2: "))
num3 = int(input(" Num3: "))

if num1 > num2 or num3:
    print(num1)

elif num2 > num1 or num3:
    print(num2)

else:
    print(num3)
```

Whatever I put, the terminal still shows input("num1")

Comment: You can also do `max(num1, num2, num3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if num1 > num2 or num3:
```

Doing this, `num3` will also have truth value.

Basically what the statement is doing

```
if (num1>num2) or num3:
```

Regardless of the fact that `num2` is less or more or equal to `num1`, `num3` will have truth value, making python execute the statement.

Change all the Statements to

```
if num1 > num2 or num1 > num3:
```

Comment: so i always have to separate them in order to get it right
thank you ^^

Answer (score 2):

`num1 > num2 or num3` means that either
`num1 > num2` or `num3` shuld be truthy and if `num3` if a number (other than 0) it is truthy. So 1st condition is always true

You should probably change it to `num1 > num2 or num1 > num3`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if num1 > num2 or num3:` you should use `num1 > num2 or num1 > num3:` because when you type if num1 > num2 or num3, it checks the condition then checks num3 is zero or not if it is not zero it returns true for your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, at @Vulwsztyn pointed out, you have an always true condition in your code. To get the soltion you want, you can use the inbuilt method `max()` to solve your question.

The code should look like:

```
num1 = int(input(" Num1: "))
num2 = int(input(" Num2: "))
num3 = int(input(" Num3: "))

print(max(num1, num2, num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*num1 = int(input(" Num1: "))
num2 = int(input(" Num2: "))
num3 = int(input(" Num3: "))

if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
    print(num1)

elif num2 > num1 and num2 > num3:
    print(num2)

else:
    print(num3)*

else:
    print(num3)
```

`or` checs if any of the condition passes. `and` checks for all conditions to pass

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing numbers in the right way, you should use an "and" instead of "or"
This is the working code:

```
num1 = int(input(" Num1: "))
num2 = int(input(" Num2: "))
num3 = int(input(" Num3: "))

if num1 > num2 and num1>num3:
    print(num1)

elif num2 > num1 and num2>num3:
    print(num2)

else:
    print(num3)
```

The short way for all this would be use the max function like max(num1, num2, num3)

Comment: great help thank you so much ^^